# Using geom_path with POSIxct dates to show trajectories over time with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, lubridate

Data:

```
segs3 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(-62132918400, -62132918400, 
-62130499200, -62130499200, -62127820800, -62127820800, -62125228800, 
-62125228800, -62122550400, -62122550400, -62119958400, -62119958400, 
-62117280000, -62117280000, -62114601600, -62114601600, -62109331200, 
-62109331200, -62101382400, -62101382400, -62098963200, -62098963200, 
-62096284800, -62096284800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Treatment = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("C", "T"), class = "factor"), cnmds1 = c(0.122961387545896, 
    0.057723977749837, 0.0300104088908616, -0.118427545586108, 
    0.232026011148594, 0.061587021296356, 0.385479649737433, 
    0.267544139583421, 0.221988530422909, -0.168855202757955, 
    0.0218318501737484, -0.231525498248828, 0.0160832637091355, 
    -0.186803075595128, -0.232613714047829, 0.0542629633219799, 
    -0.323422838323045, -0.213851711018165, -0.197755466321406, 
    -0.393692512349716, -0.0303311351612405, -0.015555599329904, 
    0.200994688464486, 0.263319025771876), cnmds2 = c(-0.206573078387224, 
    -0.0346956232380443, -0.0893959448563002, -0.0568011465358581, 
    -0.400917607471187, -0.632254641240973, -0.383454531095861, 
    -0.469614303049956, -0.215133320979806, -0.00834400437557489, 
    0.328182347160583, -0.0129823011324431, 0.350385587009896, 
    0.181878132786698, 0.667044860227797, 0.537754618186533, 
    0.327038282579616, 0.296924472706564, 0.54629597438437, 0.155846821010448, 
    -0.051982526318337, -0.075259505247973, -0.3519049986887, 
    -0.21313698658074)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), groups = structure(list(
    `Date1[, 3]` = structure(c(-62132918400, -62130499200, -62127820800, 
    -62125228800, -62122550400, -62119958400, -62117280000, -62114601600, 
    -62109331200, -62101382400, -62098963200, -62096284800), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), .rows = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 
        9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 19:20, 21:22, 23:24)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

So I'm trying to plot a trajectory based on time using some points from a NMDS analysis from two different treatments. Basically I want to show that Treatment C has a nice circular pattern over time vs. treatment T which doesn't really have that:
[image: What I'm trying to plot]

However I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. So far my code looks like this:

```
ggplot(segs3, aes( x = cnmds1, y = cnmds2)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) + 
  geom_path(aes(color = as.numeric(Date))) +
  geom_line(arrow = arrow()) +
  facet_wrap(~Treatment) + 
  coord_fixed()
```

I wanted the points to be different colors based on treatments even though they're facetted but had to give that up to convert the Date to a numeric. However the plot still doesn't show the trajectory in the correct order of time. It might be because the dates span between two years.

So ultimately my question is. How can I get trajectory lines to follow the points in the correct date sequence while also possibly coloring this line according to a gradient of time?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: With the `df` you made available, returns the same plot of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here: 1) geom_path plots the data in the order it appears in the data frame, so it needs to be sorted chronologically, and 2) `seg3` is grouped by Date, so it will be hard to sort by Date overall until you ungroup.

```
library(dplyr)
segs3 %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
ggplot(aes( x = cnmds1, y = cnmds2, color = Date)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) + 
  geom_path(arrow = arrow(type = "closed", 
                          length = unit(0.05, "npc"))) +
  facet_wrap(~Treatment) + 
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks !! Quick question. How did you know that the tibble was grouped by dates? I remember creating segs3 using group_by but if I were to be given that data how would one figure out that the first step would be to un_group?

Comment: When I printed `segs3` the output said `# A tibble: 24 x 4;   # Groups:   Date1[, 3] [12]`.  (But first it wasn't behaving when I tried to arrange by Date...)

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!